# Read an ifstream word for word into char*

Tags: c++, char, ifstream

Just trying a programming test for fun. It stipulates that I should read each word of a file, one by one.

It hints that I might want to use ifstream, but ***won't let me use std::string***, so it looks like I have to use char*

In C I would read line by line & use `strok()` as I have multiple delimiters (white-space, quotes, brackets, etc).

What the most C++ way to do this - get the words one by one - without using std::string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must make sure that you have memory allocated for your string (this part would be handled automatically by `std::string`). Then just use the normal input operator `>>`, as it will separate on whitespace.

Don't forget to free the memory you allocate (also handled automatically by `std::string`).

Lesson to be learned: Use `char` pointers for exercises like these, otherwise use `std::string`.

Comment: I am not allowed to use std::String

Comment: @Mawg Like I said in my answer, use only `char` pointers for exercises like these, when you start to code for real (or when nothing else is said about it) *then* use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file into a `std::string` and then use `std::string::c_str ( )` to retrive the nul-terminated C-style string from `std::string` object.

Comment: I am not allowed to use std::String

Comment: You have a lot of possible solutions, you can use `std::istream& std::istream::geline ( char *, streamsize )` or loop `int std::istream::get ( )` to retrive a singel character at the time. There exists also other solutions, but i think this two is the best.